# Is http://localhost/index.php/controller/action?var=val valid?

Tags: url

Some PHP MVC has the `index.php` for the front controller. Now, my question is, putting a slash `/` and `action` after the document `index.php` makes it a valid URL? Also, does `/action?var=val` means that `action` is a file, not a directory? I'm really confused if I'll follow such URL format.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a valid URL. In fact, with URL rewriting, pretty much anything can be a valid URL.

People often use the `index.php/controller/action` fallback if they *can't* rewrite the URL. It still works and they can access the URL used within PHP to still process it.